# Is there code to emulate and increase the number of CPU in a system

Tags: multithreading, cpu, scheduler, job-scheduling

This code somehow would make the OS think there are more cores on the system and dispatch threads to those. That code then should be able to take that dispatched thread and run it on a different CPU on another machine.
Of course it would have to know the specs of that machine before hand so it can expose the right CPU specs to the OS or whatever information is needed by the OS.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a distributed computing framework. Look up https://www.open-mpi.org/, for example

Comment: Re, "...and run it on a different machine..." According to the _conventional_ meaning of the word, "thread," the different threads of a single process all run in the same, shared virtual address space. That's not something that can be efficiently implemented if the threads are running on different hosts.